# ¿Como hago para que mi opción de un select, quede seleccionada después de un botón buscar y/o guardar en ASP?

Tags: asp

Como dije en la pregunta, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que la opción seleccionada por el usuario quede seleccionada después de haber apretado uno de mis botones ya sea guardar o buscar, por ahora lo que hace el código es que si le doy a una opción no se pone la que eligió el usuario, se queda en la primera opción, cabe mencionar que mi consulta esta relacionada a una clave para que me traiga estos determinados valores a mi option

Este es mi código hasta ahora

```
<select name="Punto_Tactico" style='width:300px; height:35px; color:black;'>

<%

        set rs_pTactico = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql_pTactico = "SELECT * FROM Cat_Punto_Tactico WHERE cve_adu= '"& rs_usuario.Fields("cve_aduana") & "'"
rs_pTactico.Open sql_pTactico,conn,3,3

do while not rs_pTactico.eof
    response.write "<option value="&rs_pTactico.Fields("ID_PT")&">"&rs_pTactico.Fields("Punto_Tactico")&"</option>"
    rs_pTactico.moveNext
loop
rs_pTactico.close

%>

  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dando por hecho que tendrás un form y que pulsas un botón submit, lo que podrías hacer es recuperar con Request.form el valor seleccionado por el usuario, en una variable y posteriormente, cuando estás rellenando el desplegable, dentro del bucle ir comprobando si el valor del registro dentro del bucle coincide con el valor que habías recuperado en la variable.

En caso de que coincida, rellenas el option correspondiente con "selected" y en caso contrario no lo haces.

```
<select name="Punto_Tactico" style='width:300px; height:35px; color:black;'>
<%
dim valSeleccionado = Request.form("Punto_Tactico")
set rs_pTactico = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql_pTactico = "SELECT * FROM Cat_Punto_Tactico WHERE cve_adu= '"& rs_usuario.Fields("cve_aduana") & "'"
do while not rs_pTactico.eof
    If valSeleccionado = rs_pTactico.Fields("ID_PT") Then
        response.write "<option value="&rs_pTactico.Fields("ID_PT")&" selected>"&rs_pTactico.Fields("Punto_Tactico")&"</option>"
    Else
        response.write "<option value="&rs_pTactico.Fields("ID_PT")&">"&rs_pTactico.Fields("Punto_Tactico")&"</option>"
    End If
    rs_pTactico.moveNext
loop
rs_pTactico.close
%>
</select>
```

Espero que te sirva.